# How to accept payment when abroad in a trade show?

Tags: india, international

I am planning to exhibit in a jewelry trade show in USA. I am hoping to make some sales at the show itself.
How can my clients pay me if the amounts are large (over $10000)? Smaller amounts may be settled in cash but I don't know any method to safely accept large payments from a client. How can I make sure that I receive my money, either on the spot or later?

I don't know if it's possible for me to open a bank account in USA. I'm from India.

Comment: How would you do it in India? That might help us understand what methods you're comfortable accepting.

Comment: The problem is I can not trust everyone. I can't deliver the goods to them hoping they will pay in future.

Comment: Note if you are planning on engaging in commercial activity when at the tradeshow, you would likely need a different visa when entering the US. You could not, for example, enter under a tourist visa.

Comment: Also be aware that you will have to pay sales taxes, and that there may be vendor fees imposed by the trade show, local government, or both.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the trade organisation; they may be able to make credit card arrangements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are regularly taking payments of $10,000 I'm very surprised you aren't already set up to accept credit card payments. If you are going to be doing this much in the future it would be a good thing to investigate.

Some other options might be:

- Accept cheques or wire transfers and then mail the goods to the customers once the transfer has arrived or the cheque has cleared. For goods over $10,000 the extra cost of shipping something like jewellery should be negligible. If you have someone you trust in the US you might leave the goods with them, and have them mail the goods using domestic mail when you have received payment.
- Set yourself up with a [Square account](https://squareup.com/ca). Frequently used by small businesses to take occasional credit card payments (although for $10,000 transactions a full credit card system might be better)

Answer (score -1):

I would imagine that a wire transfer would be the best way to transfer large amounts of money without the risk of carrying cash or dealing with plastic.

Comment: An international wire transfer will take days to complete. That's not going to be a good option if the OP wants to deliver the product in a relatively short time frame. Not sure if that's an issue or not though - Depends on the details of the need.